# Set StyledText in SWT ExpandItem Title/Text

Tags: swt, expand, settext, styledtext

everyone. In an `ExpandItem` in SWT, Java you're able to set the title or header text of the `ExpandItem` by using the built-in method `ExpandItem.setText(String text)`. This only supports `String` as input. I want to be able to use `StyledText` as title/header text of the `ExpandItem`. Is there a way to implement something like:

```
ExpandItem.setStyledText(StyledText text)
```

If not, what are my options? My main goal is to be able to change font style of the title/header text of `ExpandItem`. That's why I need `StyledText`.

Comment: No, there is no way to do this. ExpandItem is not designed to be extended in any way.

Comment: So my only option would be to create a custom composite which works like an expand item with my desired feature?

Comment: I suppose so. The source of ExpandBar/ExpandItem is fairly small so you might be able to reuse a lot of that.